# Why can't I invoke a function after having loaded a file that defines it?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to customise Emacs for VHDL code, and one important part is efficient code completion. I don't have much experience with Emacs, but until now I was able to define shortcuts and functions with no problem. After a quick search I found [vhdl-capf](https://github.com/sh-ow/vhdl-capf) and wanted to give it a try.

So I downloaded the file, which is a single Elisp file containing all the code. I tried many things that worked well with my earlier customizations:
`load` the file from the `init.el` file, `M-x eval-buffer` on the file, etc...

Despite my efforts, I cannot invoke the functions defined in the file and they don't even show up using completion in the mini-buffer. The weird thing is that when I `M-x describe-function` (and type the function name without completion), there is a documentation buffer appearing, so Emacs definitely knows about these functions.

A concrete example of my problem: When I `M-x vhdl-capf-main <enter>` nothing happens but a sound `[no match]` in the echo area.

So I'm lost, this is a terrible headache. Nothing about this file seems different from my other configuration files, yet it doesn't work...

Comment: those aren't interactive functions, so you can't call them with `M-x`.  Interactive functions are defined with an `(interactive)` spec as the first form in their body.  Try `M-:` `(vhdl-capf-enable)` and reload your vhdl buffer (you can add that to your hook)

Comment: @jenesaisquoi oh... I can't believe I spent so much time for this... I apparently didn't understand `interactive` correctly. 

I tried `M-: (vhdl-capf-enable)` and `vhdl-capf-main` has been added to the `completion-at-point-functions` variable, but completion does not work and this message appears: `Symbol's function definition is void: first`. 

Can you help me on that?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: that's not a package I've ever used, but `first` is a deprecated function (just an alias for `car`) in `cl.el`.  So, presumably you give `M-:` `(require 'cl)` a shot

Comment: Did you install and configure compnay-mode or some other completions framework as outlined in the instructions on the repo page? vahl-capf is not a completion solution, it is an additional backend for for a completion framework which supports fuzzy completion (like company-mode or auto-complete).

Comment: @TimX No I didn't I thought it was standalone. I will check auto-complete then. I did not test it extensively but it seemed like it was working without installing auto-complete or similar, tho.

Comment: I don't know anything about vhdl-mode, but from what it says at that link you posted, vhdl-mode comes with completion built-in. What vhdl-capf provides is 'fuzzy completion' and you need a completion framework which supports fuzzy completion, either auto-complete or company-mode. I switched to company-mode some years ago and find it very good. It might be worth getting just basic completion working with vhdl-mode before attempting to enhance the completion.